# Find the Laplace transform of $(t-\pi/2)\sin(t-\pi/2)$ using the time shift

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

> What is the Laplace transform of $(t-\pi/2)\sin(t-\pi/2)$?

I used the relationship $\mathcal{L}((t-a)f(t-a))=e^{-as}F(s)$

Hence I get $\dfrac{2e^{-(\pi/2)s}}{s^2+1}$. Would this be correct?

Comment: You mean the Laplace transform of $ u(t-a) f(t-a)$ where $u(t)$ is the unit step function.

Comment: You equation are wrong, the first term under Laplace transform should be a Heaviside step function, not just $t-a$, but rather $u(t-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be correct?

As written, it is not ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace%20transform%20of%20%28t-pi%2F2%29*sin%28t-pi%2F2%29)). Also the time shift property applies to functions that are zero for a while, i.e., contain a Heaviside factor. There isn't one in your formula. So, if the formula is correct, you just have to calculate explicitly, reducing the transform to $\cos t$ and $t\cos t$.

But if the first factor is actually the Heaviside function of $t-\pi/2$, then the time shift applies, and you indeed get $\exp(-(\pi/2)s)$ times the transform of $\sin t$. However, the latter transform is $1/(s^2+1)$, so the factor of $2$ in your answer seems extraneous.